# ERROR External table is not in the expected format when I get data from file dbf in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foxpro, dbf

My code:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString ="Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};Driverid=277;Dbq=D:\\DBF\\";
conn.Open();
OdbcCommand oCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
conn.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

When I run to oCmd.ExecuteReader() then error: 
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] External table is not in the expected format.

Answer (score 1):

You just showed your connection where your DBF file is, but didn't specified any `commandText`, Try something like that

```
oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
```